# Maven plugin build

Tags: java, maven, build

I have a maven driven project (currently we use maven 3.0.5)
We've come to conclusion that we have to develop our custom maven plugin that does some processing over our resources + running validations on them (this involves some unique logic, so we can't use existing maven plugins)

Examples of what should be done there are:

1. Validate the resources added to the module. If its an XML, check that it adheres the schema, 
   check that there is no duplication between these XMLs (according to some logic) and so forth.
   For example if I have XML:

<person>
     <name>john</name>
    <person>

I want to make sure that there is no other XML with the same name.

If its a JSON based resource, than check that it does custom logic based validations.

Its done mainly because there are too much people (the project is very big) changing these XMLs so we would like to check the stuff in compile time at least whatever we can check.

2. Prepare a custom distribution out of these XMLs (for example we create ZIP of ZIPs, each inner zip archive contains some group of those XMLs)
3. Generate some metadata based on the information found in these XMLs and add it to the inner/outer zip

Now, I would like to build the maven plugin **together** with the build of the project.
These validations can kind of change along with the logic. For example if I create new type of XML resources I can develop new kinds of validations that go beyond the validation against the schema. 
And then I want these validations running each build.

As far as I understand, in gradle there is a **buildSrc** directory for this kind of things, however in Maven I couldn't find something like that.

So my question is how we can do this in maven?

Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day

Comment: First what kind of processing do you need to do? Can you explain that a little bit more in detail? May you can use custom filtering http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/custom-resource-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get those folders injected by the following:

```java
/**
 * The list of resources we want to transfer.
 */
@Parameter( defaultValue = "${project.resources}", required = true, readonly = true )
private List<Resource> resources;
```

Comment: Thanks, if I get you right, this is the way I can access the resources inside the maven plugin. Thanks for the info, but how does this help me?. I want to build this plugin in the same build with the project. Example: I have module A and module P. A contains my code, P contains my plugin. I want to use 'mvn install' on a main pom that contains both of them and I want the P to be resolved first,build the plugin, and A would define this plugin. As far as I understand plexus resolves everything before it starts actual build, so A is invalid since plugin P is not available at resolve time

Comment: To build a plugin within the same build (reactor) you are using it is usually not a good idea in particular if you wan't to check something in your build. This means you should have plugin which is a defined version (released) state. Do you know how to [create a Mojo](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-tools-annotations/index.html) ?

Comment: Yes, I know how to create maven plugins... Its not about the __How__ to create the plugin, its only about how to make this plugin running together with the build. AFAIK Gradle has this feature, by introducing 'buildSrc' directory, I'm asking about whether maven has something similar or not... I don't think its "wrong" to demand such a check, at least in Gradle its easy, so if maven can't do that, its rather a limitation of maven... The thing is that I'm not sure that maven can't do that, that's why I'm asking :)